# Trouble comparing dictionary values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm brand new to coding, and I'm having trouble getting this function to work properly.

```
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
    """
    Returns True if word is in the wordList and is entirely
    composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.

    Does not mutate hand or wordList.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    wordList: list of lowercase strings
    """
    wordDic = {}
    if word not in wordList:    
        return False   
    for letter in word:
        if letter in wordDic:
            wordDic[letter] += 1
        else:
            wordDic[letter] =  1
    if wordDic[letter] > hand[letter]: # 
        return False
    return True
```

What I'm trying to do is compare to dictionary values of the number of times a letter occurs in the wordDic and how many times it occurs in the hand. But i keep getting "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str". Can somebody explain where I've gone wrong?

Comment: What is `hand`? It is most likely a list, not a dict. Show us the code that handles `hand`.

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: @thegrinner the one with a #

Comment: And you could use `collections.Counter()` instead of your `for letter in wordDic` loop. `wordDic = Counter(word)` saves you 5 lines of code.

Comment: Pro tip: when reporting on a python problem, always include the *full* traceback. Makes it so much easier for us when we do not have to guess where your error occurs.

Comment: Trying to debug things in python without the traceback is like trying to debug C code without a compiler :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is definitely this line:

```
if wordDic[letter] > hand[letter]:
```

And the problem is that `letter` is a character (`str`) which you're using to index your `hand` (which is apparently a `list`, not a `dict` as you expect).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `hand` is (probably) a list, not a dictionary, and you are trying to access it using `letter` which is a `str`. A list cannot be indexed using strings, hence the `TypeError`.

See the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) on lists for more.

---

`hand` is definitely a list. Test code :

```
>>> l = [1,2]
>>> l['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    l['a']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```